# Service account on Google appengine (java)

Tags: google-drive-api

How can we setup a service account authorisation with the Google Drive API, so we can act on behalf of a other user within the domain.

The code throws a HTTP ERROR 500 on line 201, see stacktrace below:

```
URI is not hierarchical

Caused by:

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not hierarchical
    at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:418)
    at com.caase.portal.DriveServlet.getDriveService(DriveServlet.java:201)
    at com.caase.portal.DriveServlet.doGet(DriveServlet.java:67)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at com.google.api.client.extensions.servlet.auth.oauth2.AbstractAuthorizationCodeServlet.service(AbstractAuthorizationCodeServlet.java:130)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
```

See the code mentioned below:

```
  /** Email of the Service Account */
  private static final String SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL = "xxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com";

  /** Path to the Service Account's Private Key file */
  private static final String SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH = "xxx-privatekey.p12";

  /**
   * Build and returns a Drive service object authorized with the service accounts
   * that act on behalf of the given user.
   *
   * @param userEmail The email of the user.
   * @return Drive service object that is ready to make requests.
   */
  public static Drive getDriveService(String userEmail) throws GeneralSecurityException,
  IOException, URISyntaxException {

  URI keyURL;
  keyURL = DriveServlet.class.getResource(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH).toURI();



HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
JacksonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();
GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
    .setTransport(httpTransport)
    .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
    .setServiceAccountId(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL)
    .setServiceAccountScopes(DriveScopes.all())
    .setServiceAccountUser(userEmail)
    .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new java.io.File(keyURL))
    .build();
Drive service = new Drive.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, null)
    .setHttpRequestInitializer(credential).build();
return service;
```

}

The line that throws the error is:
    .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new java.io.File(keyURL))

If I split up the line the error occurs in the new File creation:
    new java.io.File(keyURL)

The key file is located in: src/main/resources

Any help is welcome :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moved the resources folder from src/main/resources to src/resources and changed SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH to '/resources/xxx-privatekey.p12'. It works like a charm now!